# expressjs and socket.io - duplicate messages on client

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

i'm a begginer with Node and i'm trying to build the chat functionality with socket.io. The problem is: My client (browser) receives two messages when an event is fired.

```
app.js
var express = require('express');   
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var exload = require('express-load');
var exSession = require('express-session');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(cookieParser('ntalk'));
app.use(exSession({
  secret: 'sandman',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(methodOverride('_method'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

exload('models')
.then('controllers')
.then('routes')
.into(app);

module.exports = app;
```

---

```
//bin/www
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('express4:server');
var http = require('http');
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

/**
 * Configuring socket.io
 */
io.sockets.on('connection', function(client) {
    client.on('send-server', function(data) {
        var msg = "<b>" + data.name + ":</b>" + data.msg + "<br>";
        client.emit('send-client', msg);
        client.broadcast.emit('send-client', msg);
    })
});

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);


server.listen(port);
```

---

```
//page-script.jade
script.
    var socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
        socket.on('send-client', function(msg){
            document.getElementById('chat').innerHTML += msg;
    })

    var send = function(event) {
        var nome = document.getElementById('name').value;
        var msg = document.getElementById('msg').value;

        socket.emit('send-server', {name : name, msg : msg});
    }
```

What happens in the chat: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/a92K7.jpg

I know the files has some bad pratices, i'll refactor this as soon as i get this right :)

Comment: First, add some `console.log()` statements on the server to to track when you are sending to the client.  Then, add `console.log()` on the client in your `send()` function.  I can't reproduce your problem with the type of code you show so I'm guessing that something on the client may be calling `send()` twice and that's what you need to figure out.  I not uncommon problem is a submit button that ends up making duplicate actions. But, obviously it could be anything in the client event handling code. If you are getting dup `send()` calls in the client, then add more of your relevant client code.

Comment: client.broadcast.emit('send-client', msg);
I think problem lies here

Comment: i did the log thing, this is whats happening:  
In server side, in the `io.sockets.on('connection')` i get two connections, with different sockets IDs.  
The callback of `socket.on('send-client')` in server is fired only once, but the function `socket.on('send-client')` in client is fired twice for the same socket ID.  The send function (client) is fired only once.  If i remove the socket.emit('send-client')  the sender will receive only one message, but the other clients (other browser) receive two messages.  
If i remove the `broadcast.emit()` only the sender receive the message.

Comment: If you get two connections on the server, then there's something wrong in the client code.  Any chance your client script file is getting loaded twice?

Answer (score 5):

I know, this post is old. But has no conclusion. For future reference.

The duplication comes from here:

This line of code:
`client.emit('send-client', msg);`
**emits** the data "msg" to all sockets, **including** yourself.

This line of code:
`client.broadcast.emit('send-client', msg);`
**broadcast** the data "msg" to everyone connected to the socket, **excluding** yourself.

That's why you have 2 response from the sockets.